# When deploying a Django app in azure websites, no deployable project is found

Tags: django, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy a Django app using azure websites. My app works locally fine, but I am not able to deploy it. I get a HTTP 500 Internal Server Error.

I found this in the view log of my commit.

Found solution 'C:\DWASFiles\Sites\chocolate-chocolate\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\chocolate\chocolate.sln' with no deployable projects. Deploying files instead.

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you think you could get us a sample repro app? Perhaps the heuristic for detecting Python apps is broken.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem deploying a boiler plate node.js app.

I found the solution here:
http://nodejstools.codeplex.com/workitem/702

> I think when you create a new project you need to uncheck "Create
>   directory for solution" The issue here is that the deployment scripts
>   won't detect it as a Node.js app if the server.js/app.js is in a
>   folder.

It might be worth checking your source directory structure for a nested folder.